# Text Area not printing input when clicked button in Java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextfield, jtextarea

Heres my code guys. I have reviewed this and not sure why it is not outputting the Celcius temperature in the JTextArea once the JButton is clicked which should receive its input from the JTextField.

Heres the code...

```
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class C_to_F extends JFrame {

    JPanel layout = new JPanel();
    JLabel title = new JLabel("<html>Welcome to Farenheit to Celcius!</html>");
    JLabel inputtxt = new JLabel("<html>Input Farenheit:</html>");
    static JTextField input = new JTextField (null);
    static JTextArea answer = new JTextArea();
    static JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new C_to_F();
        frame.show();   
    }       

    public static void submit() {
        submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
                input();
            } 
        });
    }

    public static void input() {
        String TextBox = input.getText();
        float farenheit = Float.parseFloat(TextBox);
        for(int i=0;i<=0;i++) {
            double celcius = (farenheit - 32) * 5/9;
            String celciustxt = ("Celcius = " + celcius);
            answer.setText(String.valueOf(celciustxt));             
        }
    }

    public C_to_F() {
        setTitle("Farenheit to Celcius");
        setSize(300,300);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(true);
        layout.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,10,10,10)); 
        layout.setLayout(new GridLayout(8,1));          

        inputtxt.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        title.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);

        add(layout);

        layout.add(title);
        layout.add(inputtxt);
        layout.add(input);
        layout.add(submit);
        layout.add(answer);

        setVisible(true);
    }    
}
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

You haven't called `submit()` to add your listener to the button

Answer (score 1):

You never call the method `submit` which registers the `ActionListener` with the `submit` button

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the Listener on the button, e.g.:

```
submit.addActionListener(...);
layout.add(submit);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code a little. See if this works

```
public class C_to_F extends JFrame{
JPanel layout = new JPanel();
JLabel title = new JLabel("<html>Welcome to Farenheit to Celcius!</html>");
JLabel inputtxt = new JLabel("<html>Input Farenheit:</html>");
static JTextField input = new JTextField (null);
static JTextArea answer = new JTextArea();
static JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");



public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new C_to_F();
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}


public static void input() {
    String TextBox = input.getText();
    float farenheit = Float.parseFloat(TextBox);
    for(int i=0;i<=0;i++) {
        double celcius = (farenheit - 32) * 5/9;
        String celciustxt = ("Celcius = " + celcius);
        answer.setText(String.valueOf(celciustxt));


    }
}

public C_to_F() {
    setTitle("Farenheit to Celcius");
    setSize(300,300);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(true);
    layout.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,10,10,10)); 
    layout.setLayout(new GridLayout(8,1));


    inputtxt.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    title.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);

    submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
            input();
            SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(layout);
        } 
    });

    add(layout);

    layout.add(title);
    layout.add(inputtxt);
    layout.add(input);
    layout.add(submit);
    layout.add(answer);

    setVisible(true);


}
}
```